# How to static list?

Tags: console

I have this static list in my C# console application which includes different

Comment: could you please include the sample list and condition to filter `X` from those list

Comment: @fubo I posted the code

Comment: @un-lucky posted the code

Comment: well and what is  the condition for filtering `X`

Comment: X stands for a number

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways.

ex...

```
int maxCount= 4;
for(int i=0;i<maxCount && i< Mp3spelers.Count();i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]); // Write whatever your need.
}
```

Or, using `Linq`

```
list.Take(maxCount)
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However it's not working for me, when I use the first example, I get the message Soundsharp.program+mp3 4 times, like the maxCount.

Comment: Sorry I was out, what is the problem?

Comment: From all my mp3's in the static list, I want only to display 3 of them.

Comment: So change `maxCount` value to 3

Comment: Or you wan to filter specific records?

Comment: I know, but it's not displaying the mp3's, instead it's displaying 3x the sentence; "Soundsharp.program+mp3", soundsharp is the name of my application by the way.

Comment: Ahh.. that's because you need to tell which properties you want to display,  other option is overriding to string.

Comment: I made it work by telling which properties it needed to display, thanks! How to add 1 new Mp3 after clicking a keyboard key?

Comment: That's an extension to this question, I would suggest post new question. It may confuse people reaching this post if we edit the answer and extend it. Hope you understand, what I mean.

Comment: Done, can you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786316/how-to-display-new-list-item-in-c-sharp-console-application-after-pressing-a-key

Answer (score 0):

If you have overwritten `ToString()` in the `MP3` class you could use the following code:

```
public static void Display() {
   Mp3spelers
       .Where(x => /* TODO e.g. x.Name.Contains("X")*/)
       .ForEach(entry => Console.WriteLine(entry));
}
```