# How to display new List item?

Tags: console

next 2 Mp3's on the list, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display all the Mp3's that are left

You could use `Console.ReadKey` to wait for any input key, and use the same logic to print rest of the records.

```
int maxCount = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < maxCount && i < Mp3spelers.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].ID);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].make);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].mbsize);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].model);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].price);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].voorraad);
}

Console.ReadKey(); // wait for key-in

// print remaining records. 
for (int i = maxCount ;  i < Mp3spelers.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].ID);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].make);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].mbsize);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].model);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].price);
    Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].voorraad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Console.ReadKey and loop through the list again and start from the index where you left off initially.

```
for (int i = maxCount; i < Mp3spelers.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].ID);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].make);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].mbsize);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].model);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].price);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].voorraad);
        }
```

You could also make it a seperate method so you'll only have one place in your code to loop through your list and you can easily modify how many items you want to print and from what index to start printing.

```
    public void ShowItemsInConsole(int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
    {
        for (int i = firstIndex; i < lastIndex && i < Mp3spelers.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].ID);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].make);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].mbsize);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].model);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].price);
            Console.WriteLine(Mp3spelers[i].voorraad);
        }
    }
```